# Big O notation for runtime of an inventory algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o

For the sake of security, I probably can't post any of our files' code, but I can describe what's going on.  Basically, we have standalone items and others that are composed of smaller parts.  The current system we have in place works like this.  Assume we have n items and m parts for each of the kits, where m is not constant and less than n in all cases.

```
for(all items){
    if(standalone){
        process item, record available quantity and associated costs
        write to database
    }
    if(kit){
        process item, get number of pre-assembled kits
        for(each part){
            determine how many are used to produce one kit
            divide total number of this specific part by number required, keep track of smallest result
            add cost of this item to total production cost of item
        }
        use smallest resulting number to determine total available quantity for this kit
        write record to database
    }
}
```

At first, I wanted to say that the total time taken for this is O(n^2) but I'm not convinced that's correct given that about n/3 of all items are kits and m generally ranges between 3 to 8 parts.  What would this come out to?  I've tested it a few times and it feels like it's not optimized.

Comment: IF the parts in a kit have a maximum that is negligible (like 10) then consider that a constant.  Big O notation is about what happens when you have millions of parts - and when there are millions of parts then 10 is negligible.  If the maximum number of parts in a kit is 10 then it would be O(n)

Answer (score 0):

From the pseudo-code that you have posted it is fairly easy to work out the cost.  You have a loop over n items (thus this is O(n)), and inside this loop have another loop of O(m).  As you worked out nested loops mean that the orders are multiplied: if they were both of Order n then this would give O(n^2); instead it is O(mn).

This has assumed that the processing that you have mentioned runs in constant time (i.e. is independent of the size of the inputs).  If those descriptions hide some other processing time then this analysis will be incorrect.

Comment: I think the reason it takes so long is because of database access.  It reads information for each item from a table and the loop reads from the resulting array.  I created a new table before writing this script and all of the records are deleted at the beginning of this each time it runs.  The updated records are inserted thereafter.  It's probably just the database processes that take a while.

Comment: Storing each item in the database might be slow, but doubling the number of items will make it twice as slow (not 4 times as slow as O(n^2) would be).